# During or of? Which one should I use?

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct? Is there any difference at all?

> Today, you have a lot more chance to get yourself a girlfriend than at any other time of the year.

OR

> Today, you have a lot more chance to get yourself a girlfriend than at any other time during/throughout the year.

Comment: There is functionally no difference between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrases in your example

> any other time **of** the year
>   any other time **during** the year
>   any other time **throughout** the year

are all equivalent, meaning other times than the present in a typical year.  A possible subtlety is since you are using the idiomatic phrase

> *(this)* time of the year

people may immediately think of the holiday season, not just that it's an arbitrary date during the year, this may be due to the Andy Williams Christmas anthem

> [It's the Most Wonderful **Time Of The Year**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFtb3EtjEic&t=0m7s)

In your example you might want to rephrase

> you have *a lot more chance*

to

> You have *a better chance* to get a girlfriend than any other time of the year.